# Delete or filter an object in a nested array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Based on an array like this:

```
 var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: 1}, 
                 {x1: 2},
               ]
           },
         ];
```

How can I get something like this:

```
// Result of filtering an object where key is 'x1' and value is greater than 1
p === [
        {x: [
              {x1: 2},
            ]
        },
      ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = p.map(v => {
    v.x = v.x.filter(({ x1 }) => x1 > 1)
    return v
})
```

or (shorter syntax)

```
p = p.map(v => (v.x = v.x.filter(({ x1 }) => x1 > 1), v))
```

Answer (score 0):

to create a new array q with the desired properties

```
var q = [
    {x: p[0].x.filter( (x) => x.x1 > 1 ) }
]
```

or if you wish to change the array p in place

```
p[0].x = p[0].x.filter( (x) => x.x1 > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will return an array of objects with property 'x1' greater than 1.

```js
var p = [{x: [{x1: 1}, {x1: 2}]}];

let filtered = p.map(obj => obj.x.filter(y => y.x1 > 1));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

var result =  p[0].x.find(x = x.x1 > 1)

Comment: It is a very short answer but you could replace [0] for a generic response. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use map and filter

```js
var p = [
  {x: [{x1: 1}, {x1: 2}]},
];
result=p.map((o)=>({...o.x.filter(y=>y.x1>1)}))
console.log(result)
```